# Possible Graphics Driver Problem

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hardware, kerbal-space-program

I considered asking this question over at [Super User](http://superuser.com), since it may be a hardware problem, but since it's specific to one game I came here.

I have the game Kerbal Space Program. It's fairly graphics-intensive, so I want to use my better graphics processor to play it. My laptop has two graphics cards inside, and when I right-click an icon on my desktop I get a context menu

> Run with graphics processor -> High Performance NVIDIA processor

or

> Integrated graphics

When I run Kerbal Space Program with "Integrated graphics", everything works alright. When I actually launch a rocket lag is a big problem; but that's to be expected. It's not the better processor.

My question is about what happens when I try to run the game with me "High Performance NVIDIA processor". When I click that from the context menu, the game loads up a white screen in the window and stays like that. It simply hangs there with a white screen indefinitely.

Now, I've tried updating my Graphics Drivers and re-installing the game, both to little effect. I was sure that it was a hardware issue until I loaded up Minecraft with both drivers, just to see a difference. With my "Integrated graphics" I was at a steady 3 frames per second, and with my "High Performance NVIDIA processor" I had a solid 30-40 frames per second.

Some details: My "High Performance NVIDIA processor" is really a GEFORCE 310M, I'm not sure what the "Integrated Graphics" is (in Device Manager -> Display adapters I have a listing for Intel(R) HD Graphics, so that might be it), and I also have a NVIDIA Cuda card. My processor is a dual-core i5 2.67 GHz (3.2ish with turbodrive), and I'm running 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium.

This problem arose when Kerbal Space Program updated to version 0.16. Again, my apologies if this really belongs in a different place.

EDIT: Just checked with a much previous version of the game (the demo version: 0.13) and this problem is still there. I went through logs and found that I updated to Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1 right around the time that 0.16 came out, so take that as you will.

Comment: Have you tried this with a version other than 0.16?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the version of the game. It is currently version 17.1, and this problem has been persistent with every version since 16.0. I asked in their IRC and they hadn't heard of anyone else having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should choose High Performance NVIDIA processor, this is suitable with graphics device of your laptop VGA card. About integrated graphics, this software installed automatically by OS ( WIndows ) and not match driver for VGA graphics device. Don't forget to check on Device manager to ensure that graphics device driver installed correctly.